# Connecting to Zookeeper from client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, client, apache-zookeeper, client-side

I wish to connect to Zookeeper from client-side javascript. However, I can not find any suitable library for it. All the npm packages I could find are for node.js. Can someone help me with the same?

Thanks

Comment: Accessing backend services from frontend directly is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ?

Comment: @RafaeldeFreitas Yes, anything would work. As long as I can connect to the zookeeper